# Adding roles to lists in WYSIWYG blocks with Javascript

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I have a website that has a "list" content block set up with the correct accessibility roles assigned to the parent and children.

However, lists can also be added through the WYSIWYG block.

Therefore I have the below code to ensure these also receive the correct roles.

```
    var lists = document.querySelectorAll("ol, ul");
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      lists[i].setAttribute("role", "list");
    }
    
    var lists = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      lists[i].setAttribute("role", "listitem");
    }
```

What I want to do to make it as efficient as possible is to check that the ordered or unordered lists don't have a role before applying that code however I can't get this working.  I am trying the below but with no luck.

```
if (document.querySelector("ol, ul") && ![role="list"]) {

    var lists = document.querySelectorAll("ol, ul");
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      lists[i].setAttribute("role", "list");
    }
    
    var lists = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      lists[i].setAttribute("role", "listitem");
    }
    
}
```

Can someone explain why this isn't working please?

Comment: You shouldn't have to add this roles to native list elements. Why are you doing this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/list_role#best_practices . Anyways, it doesn't work because `&& ![role="list"]` is evaluated in JavaScript and either you are getting an error (strict mode) or `![...]` (not array literal) is always `falsy`, so the condition is never met.

Comment: Yes, [according to ARIA in HTML you should avoid redundant roles](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#avoid-specifying-redundant-roles). You might do so for working around certain browser bugs, but afaik there are none for list roles. Since you’re working on an authoring tool, you might be interested in [the ATAG standard](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/atag/), which includes requirements to help authors produce accessible content.